# Unable to load the mojo - maven install

Tags: maven

I am trying to install a maven project at work and getting the following error. A bit of googling shows other people with the mojo problem, but none with the specific maven-war-plug and MavenFilteringException.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project genericIntegrationServer: Executio
n default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugin
s:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
```

Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 17:31:09+0000)

Maven home: C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin..

Java version: 1.6.0_19, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.

Java home: c:\dev\jdk\1.6\1.6.0_19\jre

Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252

OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Comment: Maven is complaining (to be precise the `war` plugin is) about not being able to get to some class that it needs internally.  Is this happening as you are just setting up to use Maven?  In other words this is not something that _used to work_ and now isn't.  If so look at your `settings.xml`.  Make sure the repositories you are telling Maven to consult are accessible.

Comment: Correct this is setting up a project from the repository. I've done a clean pull, and also cleared out my .m2/repository folder too. Always get this error. Other guys here get the script to run fine from the same repository. The settings.xml file looks ok too.

Comment: The error is most definitely pointing to a class missing _somewhere in your repository_.  I understand that your settings files **looks ok**.  Can you try using the **exact** settings file that your colleagues are using (copy it or point to it)?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. Still get the same error. There's no difference between it and the repository version of setting.xml. And my colleagues confirm this from their machines.

Comment: The one foolproof way of confirming that this has something to do with the repository is by having your Maven installation point at your colleague's repository and doing an offline build.  You can do this by (temporarily) changing the value of `$HOME` (On UNIX it is `~your_user_id` on Windows it is `\users\your_user_id`).  Change it to your colleague's `HOME`.  Then run `mvn clean package -o`.  Maven will build your project using your colleague's repository.  If it runs cleanly we **know** the problem is in the repository.  If it **doesn't** run cleanly we have a head-scratcher.

Comment: Sorry, where am I changing the $HOME value? I'm on Win7.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6041/discussion-between-sri-sankaran-and-edwardmlyte)

Comment: upvoted because the title is funny

Comment: right clic on the project--> maven-->update maven project

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When I had this problem, it seemed to be a problem with my Maven install.

Uninstalling the M2Eclipse plugin and deleting the `.m2` folder on my drive, then reinstalling M2Eclipse seemed to fix it.

Comment: yeah clearing out my .m2 directory had fixed the problem. Seemed like a dodgy jar had been put in our repo

Comment: I just deleted the org\apache\maven folder and the problem got solved.

Comment: got the same problem, I only deleting the .m2 folder and it fixed the issue. No need to reinstalling M2E plugin for me

Comment: Though effective, this is like killing flies using cannons. Better use the solution by @Avinash. -1

Comment: This did technically solve my problem, Maven->Update Project did not, but might help to save the .m2 off and copy the settings.xml back in to the new one after.

Answer (score 92):

I had same issue. However, after running {Maven->Update Project} resolved the issue.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Simple and efficient. Much better than deleting the .m2 folder.

Comment: Absolutely. Maven -> Update Project is the way to go. Thanks Avinash

Comment: Solved this problem in Eclipse.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this problem or something very similar:

```
Unable to load the mojo 'resources'
```

I had just renamed some view files and had two path related errors in STS / Eclipse which I fixed but after fixing them a red X appeared next to the war line in the POM file.

"Project -> Clean" didn't help.

"Maven -> Update Project" did the trick though and cleared the error message.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this problem by doing a maven update and **force Update of Snapshots/Releases**

maven > update Maven Project > force Update of Snapshots/Releases

Yes, force update of Snapshots/Releases works for me. And I think it's  an easy way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve this error in Eclipse by doing an Maven->Update Project and checking the 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases' check box. Without checking 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases' though I continued to get the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is solved by adding a plugin

```
<build>
<finalName>some_name</finalName>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a related problem (and ended up at this question after googling).

When building from Eclipse using the Maven plugin (Run As... -> Maven install), it was failing with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1:resources (default-resources) on project *[project-name]*: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1:resources failed: Unable to load the mojo 'resources' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException

(also seen in [this coderanch post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/498681/tools/ERROR-Failed-execute-goal-org))

Building from the command line worked fine, and I noticed that in that case it was using maven-resources-plugin version 2.4.3 and not 2.4.1.

In the end I fixed this by uninstalling and then reinstalling the M2Eclipse plugin (ver. 0.12.1) like Kevin suggested. (It seemed to work without deleting the `.m2` folder)

I'm thinking the corruption might have happened when I exited Eclipse while it was in the middle of "Updating Indexes...".

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem so I deleted only the folder maven folder at **~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven** and worked for me.

All maven libraries was downloaded and the error with MavenFilteringException stopped happened.

Answer (score 2):

Just close and reopen the project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29057157)

Comment: @majidhajibaba It absolutely does provide an answer. If you don't feel like it's a *good* answer, downvote. But this isn't a comment, it's not asking a question or clarification, and it offers a solution.

Answer (score 2):

for me it solved the problem adding

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

as I use

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue got resolved by doing

Project (right click) -> Maven -> Update Project..

Comment: The question did not mention any GUI program. You provide no clue in which application you have been working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue running `clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the project root directory in terminal and run `mvn clean install`.

Then refresh the eclipse project. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply resolved this issue by deleting the repository folder in .m2, then running mvn clean install. In my case, the downloading of dependencies was aborted due to my machine shutting down, so I think one of the plugins were corrupted. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my maven was outdated in the bundle. I was using netbeans. So I first found where my maven was installed by using `mvn -version` and then copying the location. Then, on MACOS, I went to Netbeans -->  Preferences -->  Java and then Maven to finally set the maven Home to where maven is installed!